# .data LMA overlapps .data VMA addresses

Tags: c, embedded, gnu, ld

I am quite new to linker script concepts.
I have ran into some strange problems.

the sections does not seem to have the right addresses for VMA.

For example if we look at the .data sections the VMA that has been provided in inside LMA+size.
(meaning that during start-up once I copy the data from LMA to VMA the last bytes of LMA addresses will have been overwritten)

This is how the result looks like, see .data and you will see what I mean:

```
    Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .rcw          00000008  20000000  20000000  00010000  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  1 .init         00000628  20000008  20000008  00010008  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  2 .text         000177f8  20000630  20000630  00010630  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  3 .flash_data   00000010  20017e28  20017e28  00027e28  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  4 .rodata       00000ec0  20017e38  20017e38  00027e38  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  5 .xcptn        000008e8  20019000  20019000  00029000  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  6 .extram       00002080  2001a000  200198e8  0002a000  2**13
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  7 .data         000008f0  2001c080  2001b968  0002c080  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  8 .got          00000010  2001c970  2001c258  0002c970  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, CODE
  9 .got2         00000220  2001c980  2001c268  0002c980  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 10 .sdata        00000038  2001cba0  2001c488  0002cba0  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 11 .sbss         00000088  2001cbd8  2001c4c0  0002cbd8  2**2
                  ALLOC
 12 .bss          0000bbbc  2001cc60  2001c548  0002cbd8  2**2
                  ALLOC
 13 .isrvectbl    00000d88  2002881c  20028104  0002cbd8  2**2
                  ALLOC
 14 .debug_aranges 00001618  00000000  00000000  0002cbd8  2**3
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 15 .debug_pubnames 00002843  00000000  00000000  0002e1f0  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 16 .debug_info   0003f23a  00000000  00000000  00030a33  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 17 .debug_abbrev 00009c89  00000000  00000000  0006fc6d  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 18 .debug_line   0000ae64  00000000  00000000  000798f6  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 19 .debug_frame  00003bb8  00000000  00000000  0008475c  2**2
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 20 .debug_str    00007b24  00000000  00000000  00088314  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 21 .debug_loc    00015465  00000000  00000000  0008fe38  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 22 .debug_ranges 00001768  00000000  00000000  000a52a0  2**3
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 23 .comment      00000750  00000000  00000000  000a6a08  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
 24 .gnu.attributes 00000012  00000000  00000000  000a7158  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
```

the following ld-script is the one that has been provided to me:

```
    ENTRY(__start) 
/* 
 *****************************************************************
 * PE_MPC5554_rom.ld                                           
 * GNU powerpc-eabispe Linker Script for the MPC5554                                  
 * By default, this application runs in internal flash, SRAM, and cache
 * c. 2005, P&E Microcomputer Systems, Inc.
 * REV      AUTHOR       DATE       DESCRIPTION OF CHANGE
 * ---   -----------   ----------   ---------------------
 * 0.1   C.Baker FSL   19/Jul/06    Changed memory layout, stack
 *                                  variables, and filename.
 * 0.2   C.Baker FSL   21/Sep/06    Changed stack in cache address.
 *****************************************************************
 */                


MEMORY
{
/* 32M External SRAM */
        ext_ram   : org = 0x20000000, len = 0x02000000  /* 32M on the G3 board */

/* Internal Flash RCW */
/* MPC5567 2M Internal Flash, but subtract two 128K blocks for use by emulated eeprom. */ 
/* but subtract one 128K block for use by BAM. */

/* MPC5567 80K Internal SRAM */

        flash_rcw : org = 0x00000000, len = 0x8
        int_flash : org = 0x00000008, len = 0x001BFFF8
        int_sram  : org = 0x40000000, len = 0x14000
/* e4_flash is reserved for emulated eeprom in partition 9 of the High Address Space. */ 
        e4_flash  : org = 0x001C0000, len = 0x40000

}

/* The performance of applications can, potentially, be improved by locking */
/* the stack into the cache. However, as this complicates debugging (e.g.,  */
/* function parameters are not visible from GDB) it is only advisable for   */
/* production code, not during development. Set STACK_IN_CACHE to 1 in the  */
/* application's "config.inc" to lock the stack into cache. Otherwise, set  */
/* STACK_IN_CACHE to 0, and the stack will be placed at the top of the      */
/* internal RAM.                                                            */

/* Stack Address Parameters */
/* __SP_END     = DEFINED( STACK_IN_CACHE ) ? 0x40040000 : 0x40013000; */
__SP_END     = 0x40013000;
__STACK_SIZE = 0x1000;
__SP_INIT    = __SP_END + __STACK_SIZE;

/*
Optionally define this variable with the address of heap
__heap_start   =  __SP_END;
*/



/****************************************************************/

SECTIONS
{

  .rcw :
  {
    KEEP( *(.rcw) )
  } > ext_ram

  /* CRT0 startup code */
  .pecrt0 ALIGN(8) : 
  { 
    *(.pecrt0)
    PEFILL = .;
      . = ALIGN(8);
  } > ext_ram

  .interp ALIGN(8)  :
  {
   *(.interp) 
   . = ALIGN(8);
  } > ext_ram

  .hash ALIGN(8) : 
  { 
  *(.hash) 
      . = ALIGN(8);
  } > ext_ram

  .dynsym ALIGN(8) : 
  {
  *(.dynsym) 
      . = ALIGN(8);
  } > ext_ram

  .dynstr ALIGN(8) : 
  { 
  *(.dynstr) 
      . = ALIGN(8);
  } > ext_ram

  .rela.dyn ALIGN(8)       :
    {
      *(.rela.init)
      *(.rela.text .rela.text.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.t.*)
      *(.rela.fini)
      *(.rela.rodata .rela.rodata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.r.*)
      *(.rela.data .rela.data.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.d.*)
      *(.rela.tdata .rela.tdata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.td.*)
      *(.rela.tbss .rela.tbss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.tb.*)
      *(.rela.ctors)
      *(.rela.dtors)
      *(.rela.got)
      *(.rela.sdata .rela.sdata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.s.*)
      *(.rela.sbss .rela.sbss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.sb.*)
      *(.rela.sdata2 .rela.sdata2.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.s2.*)
      *(.rela.sbss2 .rela.sbss2.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.sb2.*)
      *(.rela.bss .rela.bss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.b.*)
    . = ALIGN(8);
    }                                                                    > ext_ram

  .init ALIGN(8) :  
  {     
    PROVIDE (__init = .);
    KEEP( *(.init) )
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } > ext_ram

  .text ALIGN(8) :
  {
    *(.text)
    *(.text.*)
    *(.gnu.warning)
    *(.gnu.linkonce.t*)
    __eabi = (.); /*PE*/
    LONG(0x4E800020); 
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } > ext_ram 

  .fini ALIGN(8) :  
  { 
    /*PROVIDE (__fini = .);*/
    KEEP( *(.fini) )
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } > ext_ram   

  .flash_data ALIGN(8) :
  {
    KEEP( *(.flash_data))
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } > ext_ram

  .rodata ALIGN(8) :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    *(.rodata)
    *(.rodata.*)
    *(.gnu.linkonce.r*)
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } > ext_ram 

  .rodata1 ALIGN(8) :
  {
    *(.rodata1)
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } > ext_ram

  .PPC.EMB.apuinfo ALIGN(8) :
  {
    *(.PPC.EMB.apuinfo)
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } > ext_ram AT > ext_ram

  /* ISR table for software vector mode */
  .isrvectbl ALIGN(0x800) : ONLY_IF_RO
  {
    KEEP( *(.isrvectbl) )
  } > ext_ram

  PROVIDE (__EXCEPT_START__ = .); 

  /* IVOR4Handler */
  .xcptn ALIGN(8) : 
  {
    KEEP( *(.xcptn) )
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } > ext_ram

  PROVIDE (__EXCEPT_END__ = .); 

  etext = .;
  _etext = .;  
  __etext = .;   

  /******************************************************************/
  NEXT_LOAD_ADDR = .;
  __EXTDATA_ROM = .;

  .extram : AT (NEXT_LOAD_ADDR)
  {
    *(.extram)
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } > ext_ram

  /******************************************************************/ 

  NEXT_LOAD_ADDR = NEXT_LOAD_ADDR + SIZEOF(.extram);
  /*NEXT_LOAD_ADDR = .;
  __DATA_ROM = .;*/
  __DATA_ROM = NEXT_LOAD_ADDR;

/*  .PPC.EMB.sdata2 0x20100000 : AT (NEXT_LOAD_ADDR)*/
  .PPC.EMB.sdata2 : AT (NEXT_LOAD_ADDR)
  {
    _SDA2_BASE_ = .;
    __SDATA2_START__ = .;
    *(.PPC.EMB.sdata2)
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } > ext_ram

  NEXT_LOAD_ADDR = NEXT_LOAD_ADDR + SIZEOF(.PPC.EMB.sdata2);  

  .sdata2 : AT (NEXT_LOAD_ADDR) 
  { 
    *(.sdata2) 
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } > ext_ram

  NEXT_LOAD_ADDR = NEXT_LOAD_ADDR + SIZEOF(.sdata2);  

  .PPC.EMB.sbss2 : AT (NEXT_LOAD_ADDR)
  {
    *(.PPC.EMB.sbss2)
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } > ext_ram

  NEXT_LOAD_ADDR = NEXT_LOAD_ADDR + SIZEOF(.PPC.EMB.sbss2);

  .sbss2 : AT (NEXT_LOAD_ADDR)
  {
    *(.sbss2) 
    __SBSS2_END__ = .;
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } > ext_ram

  NEXT_LOAD_ADDR = NEXT_LOAD_ADDR + SIZEOF(.sbss2);
    .data :
  {
    *(.data)
    *(.data.*) 
    *(.gnu.linkonce.d*)
    CONSTRUCTORS
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } > ext_ram

  NEXT_LOAD_ADDR = NEXT_LOAD_ADDR + SIZEOF(.data);

  .data1 :
  {
    *(.data1) 
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } > ext_ram

  NEXT_LOAD_ADDR = NEXT_LOAD_ADDR + SIZEOF(.data1);  

  PROVIDE (__GOT_START__ = .);

  .got :
  { 
    *(.got) 
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } > ext_ram 

  NEXT_LOAD_ADDR = NEXT_LOAD_ADDR + SIZEOF(.got);  

  .got.plt :
  { 
    *(.got.plt) 
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } > ext_ram     

  PROVIDE (__GOT_END__ = .);

  NEXT_LOAD_ADDR = NEXT_LOAD_ADDR + SIZEOF(.got.plt);

  .got1 :
  {  
    *(.got1) 
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } > ext_ram 

  NEXT_LOAD_ADDR = NEXT_LOAD_ADDR + SIZEOF(.got1);

  PROVIDE (__GOT2_START__ = .);

  .got2 :
  { 
    *(.got2) 
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } > ext_ram

  NEXT_LOAD_ADDR = NEXT_LOAD_ADDR + SIZEOF(.got2);

  PROVIDE (__CTOR_LIST__ = .);  

  .ctors :
  {
    /*KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.ctors))
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o) .ctors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.ctors.*)))*/
    KEEP (*(.ctors))
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } > ext_ram   

  NEXT_LOAD_ADDR = NEXT_LOAD_ADDR + SIZEOF(.ctors);

  PROVIDE (__CTOR_END__ = .);
  PROVIDE (__DTOR_LIST__ = .);

  .dtors : AT (NEXT_LOAD_ADDR)
  {
    /*KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.dtors))
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o) .dtors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.dtors.*)))*/
    KEEP (*(.dtors))
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } > ext_ram 

  NEXT_LOAD_ADDR = NEXT_LOAD_ADDR + SIZEOF(.dtors);

  PROVIDE (__DTOR_END__ = .);
  PROVIDE (__FIXUP_START__ = .);

  .fixup : AT (NEXT_LOAD_ADDR)
  { 
    *(.fixup) 
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } > ext_ram 

  NEXT_LOAD_ADDR = NEXT_LOAD_ADDR + SIZEOF(.fixup);

  PROVIDE (__FIXUP_END__ = .);
  PROVIDE (__GOT2_END__ = .);


  .dynamic : AT (NEXT_LOAD_ADDR)
  { 
    *(.dynamic)
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } > ext_ram

  NEXT_LOAD_ADDR = NEXT_LOAD_ADDR + SIZEOF(.dynamic);  

  .plt : AT (NEXT_LOAD_ADDR)
  {
    *(.plt)
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } > ext_ram

  NEXT_LOAD_ADDR = NEXT_LOAD_ADDR + SIZEOF(.plt);  

  /* We want the small data sections together, so single-instruction offsets
     can access them all, and initialized data all before uninitialized, so
     we can shorten the on-disk segment size.  */

  __SDATA_ROM = .;

  .sdata :
  { 
    __SDATA_START__ = .;
    _SDA_BASE_ = .;
    *(.sdata) 
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } > ext_ram 

  NEXT_LOAD_ADDR = NEXT_LOAD_ADDR + SIZEOF(.sdata);  

  .PPC.EMB.sdata0 : AT (NEXT_LOAD_ADDR)
  {
    __SDATA_END__ = .;  
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } > ext_ram

  __DATA_ROM_END = .;
  edata = .;
  _edata  =  .;  
  __edata = .;

  /******************************************************************/  

  .sbss BLOCK (4):
  {
    PROVIDE (__sbss_start = .);
    PROVIDE (___sbss_start = .);    
    *(.sbss)
    *(.scommon)
    *(.dynsbss)
  } > ext_ram

  .PPC.EMB.sbss0 BLOCK (4):
  {
    *(.PPC.EMB.sbss0)
    PROVIDE (__sbss_end = .);
    PROVIDE (___sbss_end = .);
    PROVIDE (__SBSS_END__ = .);
  } > ext_ram

  .bss BLOCK (4):
  {
   PROVIDE (__bss_start = .);
   PROVIDE (___bss_start = .);
   *(.dynbss)
   *(.bss)
   *(COMMON)
   PROVIDE (__bss_end = .);
  } > ext_ram

  .isrvectbl BLOCK (4) (NOLOAD): ONLY_IF_RW
  {
   . = ALIGN(0x800);
   KEEP( *(.isrvectbl) )
  } > ext_ram

  /* ISR table for software vector mode */


  /******************************************************************/

  /*
  Heap grows from lower to higer addresses
  Stack grows from higer to lower addresses
  */

  /* Define position of heap */
  /* Default to location contiguous with .bss section in RAM */
  _end = DEFINED (__heap_start) ? __heap_start : ALIGN(8);    
  PROVIDE(end = _end);
  PROVIDE(__end = _end);

  /******************************************************************/

  .gcc_except_table : {*(.gcc_except_table)}

  /* These are needed for ELF backends which have not yet been
     converted to the new style linker.  */
  .stab 0 : { *(.stab) }
  .stabstr 0 : { *(.stabstr) }
  /* DWARF debug sections.
     Symbols in the DWARF debugging sections are relative to the beginning
     of the section so we begin them at 0.  */
  /* DWARF 1 */
  .debug          0 : { *(.debug) }
  .line           0 : { *(.line) }
  /* GNU DWARF 1 extensions */
  .debug_srcinfo  0 : { *(.debug_srcinfo) }
  .debug_sfnames  0 : { *(.debug_sfnames) }
  /* DWARF 1.1 and DWARF 2 */
  .debug_aranges  0 : { *(.debug_aranges) }
  .debug_pubnames 0 : { *(.debug_pubnames) }
  /* DWARF 2 */
  .debug_info     0 : { *(.debug_info) }
  .debug_abbrev   0 : { *(.debug_abbrev) }
  .debug_line     0 : { *(.debug_line) }
  .debug_frame    0 : { *(.debug_frame) }
  .debug_str      0 : { *(.debug_str) }
  .debug_loc      0 : { *(.debug_loc) }
  .debug_macinfo  0 : { *(.debug_macinfo) }
  /* SGI/MIPS DWARF 2 extensions */
  .debug_weaknames 0 : { *(.debug_weaknames) }
  .debug_funcnames 0 : { *(.debug_funcnames) }
  .debug_typenames 0 : { *(.debug_typenames) }
  .debug_varnames  0 : { *(.debug_varnames) }
  /* */
  .eh_frame        0 : { *(.eh_frame) }

  /******************************************************************/  

__SRAM_CPY_START = ADDR(.PPC.EMB.sdata2);
__IV_ADDR     = ADDR(.xcptn);
__SRAM_LOAD      = (_end);
__SRAM_LOAD_SIZE = (SIZEOF(.flash_data) / 4);

__EXTRAM_CPY_START = ADDR(.extram);
__EXTRAM_CPY_END = ADDR(.extram)+SIZEOF(.extram);

__BSS_SIZE = ((__bss_end - __bss_start) / 4);
__SBSS_SIZE = ((__sbss_end - __sbss_start) / 4);

TEMPSIZE = SIZEOF(.PPC.EMB.sdata2)+SIZEOF(.sdata2)+SIZEOF(.PPC.EMB.sbss2)+SIZEOF(.sbss2)+SIZEOF(.data)+SIZEOF(.data1);
TEMPSIZE = TEMPSIZE + SIZEOF(.got)+SIZEOF(.got.plt)+SIZEOF(.got1)+SIZEOF(.got2)+SIZEOF(.ctors);
TEMPSIZE = TEMPSIZE + SIZEOF(.dtors)+SIZEOF(.fixup)+SIZEOF(.dynamic)+SIZEOF(.plt);
TEMPSIZE = TEMPSIZE + SIZEOF(.sdata)+SIZEOF(.PPC.EMB.sdata0);
__ROM_COPY_SIZE  = (TEMPSIZE);


__DATA_VMA = ADDR(.data);
__DATA_LMA = LOADADDR(.data);
__DATA_LMA_END = __DATA_LMA + SIZEOF(.data);

__GOT_VMA = ADDR(.got);
__GOT_LMA = LOADADDR(.got);
__GOT_LMA_END = __GOT_LMA + SIZEOF(.got);

__GOT2_VMA = ADDR(.got2);
__GOT2_LMA = LOADADDR(.got2);
__GOT2_LMA_END = __GOT_LMA + SIZEOF(.got2);

__SDATA_VMA = ADDR(.sdata);
__SDATA_LMA = LOADADDR(.sdata);
__SDATA_LMA_END = __SDATA_LMA + SIZEOF(.sdata);
}
```

EDIT1:
I get no error/warning when I *make all*.
The linker is suppose to build everything for *external memory* with starts at 0x20 000000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your linker skript tries to compress the image for storage in flash.
During runtime your image is copied to other addresses maybe because of MMU alignment restrictions.

Does the linker emit an error message or is this just that your code does not behave correctly at runtime?

The copy problem you mentioned can be easily bypassed if you copy the sections "backwards".

Copy the last item of the .data section to its runtime address, then copy the next-to-last item to its runtime address...

Comment: please discard any comments in the linker scripts, since many changes has been done by people without actually updating the comments. The linker should build the image for external memory which starts at 0x20000000. What you are suggesting should work but it seems like a dirty hack. Do you know the reason for this unreasonable VMA/LMA addresses? When I check the elf/map files everything seems to be in order meaning everything is at 0x20 xxx xxx addresses.

Comment: <long winded explanation ON> I suppose the image you build is transferred to some type of embedded system by some kind of bootloader. Most bootloader rip the image as a continous block of bytes from either some type of flash or over a network connection. Any gaps in the image (for example .xptcn and .extram would have to be saved / transmitted as explicit zeros -> waste of space / bandwidth. So the image is "compressed" by tacking the sections one after another without the required whitespace. The image itself is responsible to copy the sections to their final runtime address.

Comment: <continue> So copying backwards is not a hack in this situation. If you add the LMA of the image you can see that they are continous.

Comment: @wpaulus, shouldn´t I get some sort of error/warnings indicating that the LMA and VMA overlaps for the .data section?

Comment: No, because they are used in different situations. During runtime of your image only the VMA addresses are significant. The only time the LMA Addresses are used are in some kind image boot code that has to be carefully designed to take the section copying into account.

Comment: And the overlapping of LMA and VMA is a normal situation. (Had this myself in different projects). The reason for LMA and VMA are for bootcode

Comment: @wpaulus, thanks for all the replies. I just modified the copy/paste code with your "backward"-fix and everything seems to work. (still I am a little confused why LMA/VMA overlaps?)